# PHP strpos says different croatian chars are the same: š č

Tags: php, character-encoding

I have the following code:

```
$text = 'Tomáš'
echo strpos($text, "č");
# result if 4
```

I believe they are different chars so why is PHP telling me they are the same?
What is going on and how can I correct this?

Comment: Is this literally the code that's giving you this result? Or does `$text` come from some other source originally (e.g. a database)?

Comment: Exactly this code. My .php file is encoded on iso-8859-1 if that matters...

Comment: Since ISO-8859-1 **cannot encode** "č" or "š", uhm, yes, that would matter quite a bit...!

Comment: Actually š is valid but č is not, so that's my problem. Can you answer the question with this information so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The encoding you chose to save your source code file in cannot encode the characters you're trying to save. Whatever characters PHP is seeing, it's not comparing the strings you think it is. Save your source code in an encoding that can encode all characters, preferably UTF-8.

Comment: You are right. my IDE was fooling me and still showing me "č" or "š" but using notepad it showed me that the chars were really "c" so that's my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should try with [`mb_strpos`](http://php.net/mb_strpos) function.

> Performs a multi-byte safe strpos() operation based on number of characters. The first character's position is 0, the second character position is 1, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

With a regular setup, it returns false to me.

However if you've troubles with such special characters, using `mb_strpos` instead of `strpos` should help.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strpos.php